# Number of planets in a habitable zone with large moons

Tags: planets, earth-like, moons

I recently had an idea, and it involved moons. Excluding gas giants, roughly what percentage of planets in the habitable zones of their stars would have large moons like Earth does, as opposed to Mars and its small moons/captured asteroids?

Comment: I'm afraid there are no definitive answers to that question. Most of the exoplanets found are pretty large, much larger than Earth. We almost can't see Earth sized planets so we have no idea what is the probability of having satellites.

Comment: Also we have no odds on things which could have given us the moon like [Hypothetical Planet Theia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theia_(planet))

Comment: This is one of those questions where nobody knows the answer. Planetary science hasn't developed a cogent framework to estimate the probabilities of planets with moons. This is a good question. The trouble is it can't be answered.

Comment: You might want to drop over to [astronomy.SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) and see if someone there has some insight.  Also, attention VTCers!  Just because you can't answer a question nor believe anyone else can, it doens't mean the question should automatically be closed....